# What does "Power Off OOL" AT command mean for a Bluetooth module?

Tags: audio, uart, bluetooth, at-commands

I am reading the [datasheet for the OVC3860 Bluetooth module](https://www.electrodragon.com/w/images/4/4b/BLK-MD-SPK-B_AT_Commands_OVC3860_List.pdf) and one of the AT commands is **4.50 Power Off OOL #VX**. The description from page 21 of the datasheet is below.

[[image: ovc3860 power off ool]]

What does OOL mean in this context? I intend to use the OVC3860 as part of the [BLK-MD-SPK-B](http://www.dzsc.com/uploadfile/company/847740/20111230193854787.pdf) module if that matters.

Comment: this document states that it means `on-off logic` ... https://www.electrodragon.com/w/images/4/4b/BLK-MD-SPK-B_AT_Commands_OVC3860_List.pdf

Comment: @jsotola Can you elaborate more on what that would mean for this case? Is this turning off the part of the module that in turn determines if it should power off or is this meaning power off the actual module?